# why does window.location.pathname work in one function but not another?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to check my page slug in a function and I get an error

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I have another function that it works great in...

```
function Page() {

const thisPage = window.location.pathname.slice(1); 
console.log(thisPage);
....
```

Today I am trying to use it here below, but I get the error above

```
export default function Page() {
    
const thisPage = window.location.pathname.slice(1); 
console.log(thisPage);
```

Why does the code work in one function but not the other?

Comment: It looks like your error is being generated on the server. If so, the window object does not exist as you are not in the browser.

Comment: The React components in Next.js are rendered on the server as well, which doesn't have a `window` object. It's good practice to guard against that with e.g. `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { /* do some browser specific stuff */ }`

Comment: thanks guys.. I did have tha Tholle but removed as it  wasn't working anyway (no error, but also no log) . How should i write that for next?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with `thisPage` once you have it, and if it's necessary to run it on the server or if it's sufficient to just run it in the browser.

Comment: it will be my page slug, my plan is to use it to make a JSON query with GraphQL for the matching page slug and then display the data.. the JSON is from wordpress, to make a headless CMS

Comment: im trying to come up with troubleshooting techniques as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.js does it like this

`router.pathname;`